# Flutter mobile_scanner gets disabled when navigating from a screen that already contains scanner

Tags: flutter

I'm using mobile_scanner in my project. When navigating from a screen that uses the scanner to another screen that also uses it; On the second screen, the scanner viewport becomes blank. Scanning also does not work.

This is my basic setup

```dart
// Screen A (Stateful Widget)
late final controller = MobileScannerController();

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      MobileScanner(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    FilledButton(
      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
  )
}


// Screen B (Stateful Widget)
late final controller = MobileScannerController();

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MobileScanner(
    controller: controller,
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you dispose the controller in an overridden `dispose` method of the stateful widgets? I am not sure whether the package takes care of it or you should, but if the controller remains alive maybe it causes your problem.

Comment: Yup I'm disposing it. I'll update the posted code.